# Retrieve Single Value only

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select fap.provider_id where fap.LOB = 'WMR'
```

some fap.provider_id have multiple fap.LOB ('WMR, 'WMC'), how to retrieve fap.provider_id with only one fap.LOB) I only want provider having single fap.LOB only.

Comment: Your `SELECT` statement is syntactically incorrect because there is no `FROM` clause. You might want to edit your question and correct that issue. In addition, we have no idea how your table is structured, nor how there could be multiple "LOB" values. You might want to add the definition of the table to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
select   provider_id
from     fap                            --  I assume...???
group by lob                            --  not sure if "lob" is a reserved word... check?
having   count(lob) = 1 
   and   max(lob)   = 'WMR'
;
```